# Jhipster gateway add /services to all my request

Tags: jhipster

I've set up my new gateway and a microservice for testing purpose.
The microservice has a single entity with only one field.
The gateway recognize the microservice in gateway Tab of the administration panel over the web interface, but in the URL i see /services/test/** .
If i try to use the swagger integrated in the interface the request is generated with the same url.
And i'm getting always error 401.
I didn't find something useful in other questions.

I just want to know how to remove that /services in the URL because the test miscroservice is mapped like : localhost:8080/test/api/tests

I'm using jHipster 6.0.1
I'm using JWT Auth
Everything is build with Maven.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, both the integrated Swagger and the Swagger on the JHipster Registry work without a 401 (for JWT auth).  What authentication type are you using?  The `/services` comes from the prefix applied to Zuul routes https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/ca475341d63ee7540a0f15f8a954dea16ebf5cf1/src/main/resources/config/application.yml#L49

Comment: i'm using JWT authentication, and the project is build through maven.

Comment: i have tried the same set up with jhipster 5.8.2 and everything is fine.
so i tried to contact the microservice build with jhipster 6 from the gateway build with jhipster 5.8.2 , that make the right request ( lh:8080/test/api/tests) but the response is again 401 . the same is with gateway v. 6 to misroservice v.5.8

Comment: There were breaking changes in v6 so I would not recommend mixing the versions v5 and v6.  Sadly I still could not reproduce even when mixing versions so don't know what could help